# How to compile program with _mm_clflushopt function? error: inlining failed

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, intrinsics

I googled a lot but I could not manage to succeed in compiling C program using `_mm_clflushopt` function. `_mm_clflush` works fine but I want to be able to try optimized version as well. I checked in cpu flags and clflushopt is included. I am using  emmintrin.h and  immintrin.h both libraries but at compilation I still get "undefined reference to _mm_clflushopt" error. I am running gcc -o prog prog.c in linux terminal.
Using x86intrin.h library gives me this error during the compilation:

```
error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '_mm_clflushopt'
```

[image]

I would appreciate any help, I am super new to this instructions though after trying to find more information, I was not really able to find C code with optimized version. That's why I decided to ask a question.

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message as text, not an image.  Your image doesn't help anyone with the same problem find this with a google search on their error message.

Comment: Hello, sorry this was my first questions so I thought picture was ok, but I will definitely take this advice into account for the next time and type the error code.

Comment: It's not too late to fix *this* question with an [edit].

Comment: I added typed error as well. Hope is ok now.

Comment: If you make your edit while logged in as the account that originally posted, you don't have to wait for the edit to be reviewed and approved.  But yes, that's what was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC only lets you use intrinsics that the target CPU supports.  GCC will never emit `clflushopt` on its own, but this rule makes more sense for extensions like AVX2, where gcc does know how to auto-vectorize with AVX2 if you let it.  And you have to enable usage of AVX2 instructions before GCC will allow itself to emit them, even if your source uses intrinsics.

**Use `gcc -O3 -march=native` to enable use of all the extensions present on the CPU you're compiling on.**  (`-march` still works without enabling optimization, but I put it in for future readers that are going to copy/paste the bolded part.)

Or `-march=skylake` or `-march=znver1` (Zen) for example to compile for a specific target CPU regardless of what host you're compiling on.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html

**The specific option for just CLFLUSHOPT is `-mclflushopt`**, but using `-march=skylake` also sets `-mtune=skylake`, which you also want.  And enables AVX2 and earlier, FMA (yes that's separate from AVX2), and BMI1/BMI2, popcnt, RDRAND, RDSEED, and lots of other goodies.  (Compile with `-march=skylake -fverbose-asm -S` and look at the asm comments at the top of the file to see all the `-m` options enabled / not enabled.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. I used gcc -O3 -march=native and compiled without any problem. Also thank you for such a comprehensive answer, it will be useful for me in the future as well.

Comment: Hello, I have one question regarding -O3 flag. It's for optimization right? But if I use -O0 then is it guaranteed that in run time order of my load operations won't be changed? I was going to make sure of that order using _mm_lfance() but it does not behave reliably so I want to test without it.

Comment: @AnaKhorguani:  `-O0` will stop any compile-time reordering, except within the same statement where there was no ordering guarantee anyway.  The x86 memory model already stops load-load reordering at runtime. 
  `_mm_lfence()` doesn't order stores, so stores can reorder past an lfence *and* a clflushopt.  Intel's manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clflushopt) suggests sfence to order clflushopt.  (But yes, interestingly the manual does say that `clflushopt` is ordered wrt. "fence instructions", so that would seem to include `lfence`.